# Inheritance with abstract class in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class, abstract

I want make a simple inheritance instances, on which there is a lot of info on the internet, but I just can't understand it in my case.

```
public abstract class Board {       
    private Block [][] board;               
    /**
     * creates and empty board
     */
    public Board(){
        board = new Block[6][6];

        //init board
        for(int i = 0; i<board.length ...

    }

    public abstract place(int x, int y, int type);

    public void otherFunction1();

    etc..
```

And my child class

```
public class StandartBoard extends Board{

    public int place(int type, int x, int y) {
        bord[i][j].something;
    }
```

The deal is, that I want to use the initialization from the super class's constructor and also all of it's other functions, but I want place function to be specific for the StandartBoard. How hould I define variable "board", so I can use and modify the same varaible from the super class.

I know one way is with sets and gets, but can't I have acces to it directly with protected or something ...

Comment: `"can't I have acces to it directly with protected"` - Yes.  Did you try doing *exactly that*?

Comment: There's maybe a typo in your example code. `bord`in ` bord[i][j].something;` should possibly be `board`?

Comment: Yes, I did :) I read that with protected, everybody gets access to it (not only the child class, but all classes in the package). Or did I understand the table from oracle wrong? I want such type of access, so only this child class to be ably to modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set your `board` with the `protected` modifier rather than `private`, then you could have direct access to it, like you suggested.
Another approach (doesn't necessarily reflect the correct practice), also as you stated, is to define a `getter` for it:

```
public Block[][] getBoard(){
    return board;
}
```

Regarding your comment, yes, `protected` has package-wide access. There is no *subclasses-only* modifier. Java originally had such a modifier. It was `private protected`, but was removed in Java 1.0.

If you wish to emulate such design, you may use the `protected` modifier and enforce that only the parent class and its subclasses are in the same package.

Comment: I would not use a public getter on the array in this scenario, because it exposes the array reference, and now your `Board` class can no longer guarantee that the `board` object is in a valid state because anyone that can read the board can now modify any element in the board. Making `board` to be `protected` is the best way to expose it to subclasses.

Comment: Added a comment about that in parenthesis

Comment: Protected means that only the child class can access it and nobody else? (Not other classes from packages etc)

Comment: @Mladia I expanded my answer to address that issue

Answer (score 0):

You have read the table from Oracle correctly.

`protected` means that the field can be accessed from *any* class in the same package (even if not a subclass) **and** from subclasses in different packages. That probably isn't what you want - default access (no modifier) would probably be preferable to using `protected`.

There is no modifier that means that *only* subclasses can access it.

You are probably better of keeping `board` `private` and ensuring that all methods that change it keep it in a consistent state. Since an array is mutable, you could provide a `public` getter for an individual entry rather than for the entire array

```
public Block getBlockAt(int i, int j) {
    return board[i][j];
}
```

That way you can read the board from anywhere without making it possible to change the board from anywhere.